# How can i automatically save pdf without click on Save button after window.print event fire

Tags: pdf, printing

Here is my code..

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
      function printPage()
      {
         var html="<html>";
         html+= document.getElementById('block1').innerHTML;

         html+="</html>";

         var printWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status  =0');
         printWin.document.write(html);
         printWin.document.close();
         printWin.focus();
         printWin.print(); 
         printWin.close();
      }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="block1">
          This is Block 2 content
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="Print Block 1" onclick="printPage();"></input>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can i automatically click or download pdf file, without click on save button after open print window..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5QPb.png)

Comment: Note: there is no such thing as a closing tag for `<input>`

Comment: @rob by mistake added...